# UITableView pass data to a Tab Bar

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView, and I need to pass data from the table to a Tab Bar that contains three items (3 viewController), in the prepareForSegue function, 
i can refer to the first and the last items of the Tab Bar as the following:

```
let desView: nextPageViewController = 
    secondScene.viewControllers?.first as! nextPageViewController

let desView2: next2ViewController = 
    secondScene.viewControllers?.last as! next2ViewController
```

then passing data to the first and the last view controllers as the following

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let currentPhoto = sectionArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            desView.currentPhoto = currentPhoto
            desView2.currentPhoto = currentPhoto
```

The question is: How can I refer to the viewController in the middle, the Tab Bar comes with 2 items by default and I had to add the third manually, so that using the above function we can refer only to first and last.
Is there an another way to refer to the viewControllers inside the tab bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access any object in the array by its index, like this:

```
secondScene.viewControllers[0]
secondScene.viewControllers[1]
secondScene.viewControllers[2]
```

etc

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.